# How to pass an integer value to other forms?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to use a label? I'm planning to display a scoring system, like every correct answer the score will add 10pts.

Comment: Take a look https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAAxqTK1W-k

Comment: Pass it in the constructor for your form...

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] as this is poorly asked.

Answer (score 1):

Use an instance of a class within a form. The Form can call methods of the Class. The Class can raise events to the Form. Don't talk directly from a Class to a Form. Or from one Form to another.

Form1 with TextBox1:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private myClass1 As Class1
    Private myForm2 As Form2

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        myClass1 = New Class1()
        myForm2 = New Form2(myClass1)
        myForm2.Show()

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        myClass1.SetText(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Form2 with Label1:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private WithEvents myClass1 As Class1

    Public Sub New(instance As Class1)
        InitializeComponent()
        myClass1 = instance
    End Sub

    Private Sub myClass1TextSet(value As String) Handles myClass1.TextSet
        Me.Label1.Text = value
    End Sub

End Class
```

Class1:

```
Public Class Class1

    Private text As String = ""

    Public Event TextSet(value As String)

    Public Sub SetText(value As String)
        Me.text = value
        RaiseEvent TextSet(value)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Form2.Label1 will update as you type in Form1.TextBox1. You may change it around as you need to fit your application, but try to keep this structure.

Form >> instance >> Class

Class >> events >> Form

The form instantiating the other form is for simplicity of this example. Larger scale projects could have a form loader factory responsible for making forms.

Comment: @Zaggler Nothing was **linked** when I posted this answer. **Related** questions (including one nominated as duplicate) do not apply because `every correct answer the score will add 10pts` may not work very well with the one-shot constructor solution. Which one did you have in mind anyway?

Answer (score 0):

In your Form2 add a public shared integer

```
 Public Shared score As Integer = 0

 Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

 End Sub
```

Then in Form1 increase it by adding to it

```
 Form2.score += 50
```

Comment: ...and then what?

Comment: OP said he wanted to do a score system, now he has a score that can be accessed by both forms so he can display it in the second form or do whatever.

Answer (score -1):

for example 
Add two forms to project
in Form2 define Label1 control
and in Form1

```
Public Class Form1
    Private intScore As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.Label1.Text = intScore.ToString
    End Sub
End Class
```